# Bash redirection: since `&> foo` means `> foo 2>&1`, is there a `&>>`?

Tags: bash

Following would redirect the Stdout and Stderr to `logfile`:

```
$ command &> logfile
```

How do I do this redirection without overwrite `logfile` during next run of `command`. Something like `>>` if it was a plain redirection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could attach stderr (2) to stdout (1) and then redirect stdout in append-mode:

```
command >> logfile 2>&1
```

The `2>&1` bit attaches stderr to stdout and then you redirect stdout to append to `logfile` in the usual manner.

Comment: @yi_H: better now? I usually use `2>&1` with pipes.

Answer (score 4):

From the BASH manual

> ```
> The format for appending standard output and standard error is:
>        &>>word
> This is semantically equivalent to
>        >>word 2>&1
> ```

<strike>So, `$ command &>> logfile`.</strike>

**EDIT**: The shorthand version seems to be a feature in bash version 4, so for compability reasons you should use `command >> logfile 2>&1`.

Comment: Does this work for you? The standard OSX bash (3.2.48) yields a syntax error: `syntax error near unexpected token '>'`.

Comment: Yes and no. I first tried it on Cygwin bash (4.1.10(4)), which worked. Now that you said it did not, I also checked two other versions, Ubuntu with bash 4.1.5(1) which worked, and Solaris with bash 3.2.51(1), which didn't. So I guess it's a version 4 feature?

Comment: Yeah, looks like a version 4 thing. The `2>&1` version should work everywhere though.

Comment: It won't work atleast on bash

$ ls test1 &>> test
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `>'

Comment: @jay, what version are you using? (`bash --version`)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections), what you're  after is what you may have guessed:

```
$ command &>> logfile
```

Notice the doubled `>>` to append.

Answer (score 0):

You answered your question in your question....

```
$ command &>> logfile
```

Comment: But it looks like `&>>` is a bash-4 thing and I'm guessing that jay's using OSX which still ships with bash-3.